# Javascript + MEAN stack: How to properly find "_id" field (not "id") in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, mongodb, mean

I have Angular app with MongoDB from where I grab data to array named books that has one entry and looks like this:

```
{_id: "5b768f4519d48c34e466411f", name: "test", reservation: null, reserved: false, __v: 0}
```

with a TypeScript interface

```
interface Books { 
    id?: Number; 
    name: String; 
    reservation: Number; 
    reserved: Boolean; 
}
```

I'm trying to find reserved value from this array entry based on "_id". The other "id" variable without underscore that is after === is injected when button is pressed that runs below code:

```
findBook(id) {
      const result = this.books.find( sfid => sfid._id === id);
      console.log('reservation for this book is: ' + result.reserved);
        // todo: do something if book is reserved
    }
```

Now this works just fine and I get the result but in Angular debugger I get below error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/index/index.component.ts(24,56): error
>   TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Books'.

That said how should I properly search using "_id" value name? Replacing "sfid._id" with "sfid.id" does not work.

Comment: So what does your `Books` interface/class definition look like?

Comment: The error just means that your `Book` interface does not implement `_id`. Just add `_id : string;` to it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: interface Computer {
    id?: Number;
    name: String;
    reservation: Number;
    reserved: Boolean;
  }

Comment: Um... that's the `Computer` interface, not `Books`...

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, will try it too.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes my mistake Computer and Books  interfaces looks similar so I did paste it by mistake here is Books one: interface Books {
    id?: Number;
    name: String;
    reservation: Number;
    reserved: Boolean;
  }

Comment: The answer that you have currently accepted, is just a workaround that circumvents TypeScript's type checking. The solution proposed by @JeremyThille is better.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes JeremyThille solution works and I think is indeed better answer but sadly I cannot mark comments as answers so I did mark A. Todkar as it works too and it may help someone in future that do not read comments.

Comment: @JeremyThille Reputation up for grabs buddy! Turn your comment into an answer and profit :)

Comment: Fair enough, I did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is only a workaround to make Typescript stop complain about _id not being implemented in the interface. The real fix is to implement it:

```
interface Book {
   _id : string; // <-- Add this
   name: string;
   reserved : boolean;
   reservation : any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access object properties like array elements in javascript.

```
const result = this.books.find( sfid => sfid["_id"] === id);
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: This works, but it is just a workaround to make Typescript stop complain about `_id` not being implemented in the interface. The real fix is to implement it (see my comment)

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is happening on the server side:

MongoDB uses `ObjectID`s for it's `_id` fields, so it's not a string and your '===' operator won't work.

My solution is usually to parse those objects at the server side.
You can easily do that by wrapping the object with string, since they implement `toString` function:

```
String(yourObjectId)
```

So in your case:

```
this.books.find(sfid => String(sfid['_id']) === id)
```

Comment: OP clearly states that the code works fine, but that Angular (client-side) reports a TypeScript error. How will your answer do anything to address this?